# elasticsearch must OR must_not

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have this query for my elasticsearch request:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should" : [
                        {                
                            "bool" : {
                                "must_not": {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "visibility_id"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool" : {
                                "must": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "visibility.visibility": ["visible"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to check if the row `visibility_id` is in the table. If not it will return true has it   reach the "must_not". But if the `visibility_id` column is present it needs to check that this is set to "visible".

At the moment it works if the `visibility_id` is `null` but it does not check the `terms`. `terms` can be anything else but `visible` and it will works.

Can someone help me please, I am new to elasticsearch. (I have tried without the filter, bool, only with the should but it does not work neither.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, you're missing `minimum_should_match: 1`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "visibility_id"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "visibility.visibility": [
              "visible"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If `visibility` is `nested` in your mapping, your query needs to be like this instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "visibility_id"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "visibility",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "visibility.visibility": [
                  "visible"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does filter affects anything ? Because it does not work with or without filter even with minimum_should_match

Comment: it makes no sense to nest should inside filter, what you want is to have either one of the constraints match and you do that with should + minimum_should_match

Comment: Okay this is what I have and it still does not care about the terms "visible", how can i replace that with match ?

Comment: Can you show a document that matches but shouldn't?

Comment: "visibility": {"visibility": "hidden"} it shouldn't match as visibility.visibility != "visible"

Comment: Do you mind sharing your index mapping?

Comment: Yes I can't share it...

Comment: At least the `visibility` field mapping

Comment: but it works when my query only do this "match" : {
        "visibility.visibility": {
            "query": "visible"
        }
      }
But it does not manage if visibility is null

Comment: I think I am missing something because this is returning everything that does not have the "visibility_id" row, and not only one specific table

Comment: What's the mapping of the `visibility` field?

Comment: (what is the mapping?) I only understand now that I am looking over all indices and I have to make the query inside a nested: {}

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to check. if `visibility` is of type `nested`, then the above query doesn't work. I've updated it

Comment: Yes this is nested inside multiple object : object1.visibility and the object visibility has a value visibility itself so it is like this object.visibility.visibility. But I have to check if object.visibility exists in my table

Comment: Then you need to use the full path

Comment: Thank you! It finally works

Comment: I just edited the answer so it is exactly what I have working :)